# compare 2 stl files

Tags: compositing-nodes, image

I would like to compare 2 stl files. My goal is to receive a difference between enclosed files. The files show teeth before and after preparation. I would like to use Blender software to show how many millimeters of teeth was removed in preparation process. I would appreciate any help which give me guideline how I can create an evaluation of teeth preparation accuracy.

Thank you in advance!
Best Regards

Marcin

files:
https://ufile.io/5x5p7 https://ufile.io/ckscr

Comment: LIttle bit off of the goal, but blender might not be optimal for a difference analysis, I tried to do it for a while and had a lot of trouble. Have you looked into using [meshlab](meshlab.net) to do this. I have found it a whole lot easier to see the difference, though I had some problems with using actual units.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have not used meshlab yet. I tried it with Geomagic Studio, unfortunately, the trial has run out and now, I'm looking for some open source, thank you for your hint!

Comment: Then meshlab is pretty good. its open source.